# Add attibute to tag using XSL

Tags: html, xml, xslt, web, xhtml

So I have a xhtml tag in my code that is like this...

```
<input type="checkbox" name="test" id="radio3" value="test"/>
```

However, I pull in data through my XSL file which I use to format my html document. I was planning to use an if statement so that the data it pulls, if it follows a certain criteria then the checkbox will be ticked. So essentially I will add an attribute so that the resulting html will look like...

```
<input type="checkbox" name="test" id="radio1" value="test" checked=""/>
```

At first I used If statements...

```
<xsl:if variable="//o:TEST = 'Y'">
      <input type="checkbox" name="test" id="radio1" value="test" checked=""/>
</xsl:if>
<xsl:if variable="//o:TEST = 'N'">
      <input type="checkbox" name="test" id="radio1" value="test"/>
</xsl:if>
```

This worked fine... however I found that my Model file could not read the data and I am assuming that it has something to do with how XSL processes the data after the Model gathers data.

So I was wondering how I would go to or if someone could lead me in the right direction in how I could manipulate the actual data that is already within my HTML. (So rather than generating the checkbox inputs within my XSL file, I would instead add the checkbox inputs in my HTML file and then would the checkbox inputs from the HTML file).

Cheers

Comment: How about JavaScript as an alternative. With JS you can easily add attributes or create a new input. Maybe you can even consider jQuery - to make it simpler.

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of animal your "Model file" is, but I think you are right that the problem is not your XSLT per se, but its role in your overall processing pipeline. You might like to look at Saxon-CE, which operates directly on the HTML DOM in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

You could modify the `<input>` elements depending on a condition instead of creating new `<input>` elements like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns="" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="2.0"  xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="input">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="1=1">                    
                    <xsl:attribute name="checked"></xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*|text()"/>
        </xsl:copy>        
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*|text()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*|text()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have tested with this input:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="checkbox" name="test" id="radio3" value="test"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

And it created the `checked=""` attribute:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="checkbox" name="test" id="radio3" value="test" checked=""></input>
    </body>
</html
```